# Deserialize Json to List C#

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm having some issues on deserializing a Json that the api returns.

The Json is the following:

```
{ "Result":[
    {
        "Id": 1, 
        "Type": "Type1"
    },
    {
        "Id": 2, 
        "Type": "Type2"
    }
]}
```

I'm trying to deserialize it to a list of this type:

```
public class ContactType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

The ReturnType used below is: `List<ContactType>` and the function `GetContactTypes<ReturnType>` is called this way:

```
var test = await _items.GetContactTypes<List<ContactType>>(AuthToken.access_token);
```

Using this code:

```
    public async Task<ReturnType> GetContactTypes<ReturnType>(string access_token)
    {
        try
        {
            Header = string.Format("Bearer {0}", access_token);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", Header);

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(base_url + "contacttypes");

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReturnType>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }
            else
            {
                return default(ReturnType);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return default(ReturnType);
        }
    }
```

But I always get this error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Comment: If you generate the C# classes for this JSON at http://json2csharp.com/ you will see that it creates two classes: `Result` and `RootObject`. Your code is failing because it is trying to deserialize the JSON to type `List<ContactType>` when it is actually of type RootObject with a containing `List<Result>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object you're trying to deserialize has a single property `Result` containing the array of `ContactType` - you dont have that in your object model. Try deserializing to this object:

```
public class MyClass // give this a more meaningful name
{
    public List<ContactType> Result{ get; set; }
}

public class ContactType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
...
var test = await _items.GetContactTypes<MyObject>(AuthToken.access_token);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a wrapper class for this, since the json object is not just an array itself but with a node `"Result"` with the value of that array.

```
public class ContactResult
{
    public List<ContactType> Result {get; set;}
}
```

And then call your method with that wrapper class:

```
var test = await _items.GetContactTypes<ContactResult>(AuthToken.access_token);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you generate the C# classes for this JSON at json2csharp.com you will see that it creates two classes: ContactType and RootObject:

```
public class ContactType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<ContactType> Result { get; set; }
}
```

Your code is failing because it is trying to deserialize the JSON to type `List<ContactType>` when it is actually of type RootObject with a containing list.

So if you deserialize to type of `RootObject` first like so:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(str)
```

You can then access the list inside of the deserialized `RootObject` object.