# Can't get JSON to deserialize into a list?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization

I'm working on a bot that will pull from a list of trivia questions stored in JSON, but it seems to not be able to recognize the JSON as a list, even though I THINK I have it said up correctly.

Pertinent Code:
C#:

```
class Question
{
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public bool asked { get; set; }
}

class TriviaGame
{
    public List<Question> QuestionList = new List<Question>();

    public TriviaGame()
    {
        QuestionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Question>>(File.ReadAllText(@"filepath"));
    }
```

JSON:

```
{
    "Question" : [
    {
        "Catagory": "text",
        "QuestionText": "text",
        "Answer": "text",
        "Points": integer,
        "Asked": false
    },
    {
        "Catagory": "text",
        "QuestionText": "text",
        "Answer": "text",
        "Points": integer,
        "Asked": false
    },
    {
        "Catagory": "text",
        "QuestionText": "text",
        "Answer": "text",
        "Points": integer,
        "Asked": false
    }]
}
```

Replaced the text in the JSON file with placeholder text but the values aren't the problem it verifies fine.
Replaced the actual filepath with the word filepath for privacy reasons but the filepath works because it DOES pull up the file before throwing the error.

Error Given:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Cannot deserialize the
> current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TriviaBot.Question]' because the
> type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To
> fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])
> or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
> not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
> or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
> JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
> deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'Question', line 2, position 13.'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deserialize Json to List C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612787/deserialize-json-to-list-c-sharp)

Comment: In case you're interested, that's a DataSet, with a DataTable named `Question`. So, you can deserialize it as `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(...)` If you replace those `integer` things with an actual value, that is.

Comment: Or DataTable directly: `var q = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("Question").ToString());` or a List of Question objects, just replace DataTable with `List<Question>`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the JSON file; it describes a map and not an array.
Try deleting

```
{
"Question" :
```

at the start and deleting the `}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON structure you have has a property named Question that has an array of items, not an array of questions.

As [Roy Cohen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64252708/cant-get-json-to-deserialize-into-a-list/64253838#64253838) states, you could modify your JSON file and remove the `Question` property.

Alternatively, if you can't modify that structure (for example if you get it from a service that you don't own), you can modify your class definition as follows:

```cs
class Items
{
    public List<Item> Question {get;set;}
} 
class Item
{
    public string Catagory { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }
    public int Points { get; set; }
    public bool asked { get; set; }
}
```

And then to load the object, use this code:

```cs
public List<Item> QuestionList = new List<Item>();

public TriviaGame()
{
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Items>(File.ReadAllText(@"filepath"));
    QuestionList = deserialized.Question;
}
```